# authorized.net Direct post payment error while place order with magneto 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

[image: error popup message]

while place order with **authorized.net Direct post-payment** it shows error **sorry something went wrong please contact seller**, I double-checked **authorized.net Direct post**  configured, and applied **patch** also from  https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024368392-Update-Authorize-Net-Direct-Post-from-MD5-to-SHA-512

all are correct,

please  suggest a proper clue

Comment: Check your payment log and network tab response

Comment: in network- Status Code: 200 OK  response- 0A210224B8614A9D21C28FFF5B811AB48F77A054588209CD2ACDAD7C4CBFDF82875D736F7CF6EF73D2823D64A2E9182EAFF82AF5E934BD48AD1F2F006F7DA8B0","controller_action_name":"directpost_payment","is_secure":""}}}

Comment: in payment.log ,  array (
  'request' => 
  array (
    'x_version' => '3.1',
    'x_delim_data' => 'FALSE',
    'x_relay_response' => 'TRUE',
    'x_test_request' => 'TRUE',
    'x_login' => '****',
    'x_method' => 'CC',
    'x_relay_url' => 'http://majorleaguevapers.dev:9005/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response',
    'x_type' => 'AUTH_ONLY',
    'x_fp_sequence' => '8546',
    'x_invoice_num' => '100032739',
    'x_amount' => 22.99,
    'x_currency_code' => 'USD',
    'x_tax' => '0.00',
    'x_freight' => '0.00',
    'x_first_name' => 'Joe',

Comment: now Raj mohan  is there any error need to fix

Comment: are you using sandbox or production account

Comment: this one using https://sandbox.authorize.net/

Comment: In sandbox mode you would not be getting success messages in front end

Comment: I  checked my sandbox  Search for a Transaction  there is no deduction list of payment  and   magento2 admin dashboard shows the pending product

Comment: how  can I resolve these 2  error msg popup and payment details after place order